# ember - change property of view from action handler

Tags: javascript, html, ember.js

i have a splitscreen layout master/detail and my detail section is included as view `{{view 'details'}}`

Additional I have this JS definition for the view:

```
App.DetailsView = Ember.View.extend({
  templateName:"details",
  model: {
      customer: 'Bob'
  }

});
```

The model property is accessible `{{view.model.customer}}`

So but now I want to change my model property from in an action handler of a button in my side navigation.

Any Ideas ?

Cheers Marvin

Comment: What problem are you facing when you try to do that?

Comment: I don't even have a Idea how to do it the only thing I tried was this line from my action handler: `this.controllerFor('details').set('model',newmodel);` but didn't worked at all..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it on my own after I understood that I can easily define it like I did shown in my question and later instance it like this:

```
var details = Ember.View.create({
                templateName: 'details',
                model: {
                  customer: 'Bob'
                }
              });
```

From now on I can manipulate my view by removing and appending it again.

with: `.remove()` and `.append()` or `.appendTo('#id')`